# Regex not working as expected - PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I have string which contains a variable in curly braces and I want to replace them with a value.

```
$text = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name}## and I am ##{Adjective}##';

preg_match_all('/{([^#]+)}/i', $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    $text = str_replace('{' . $value . '}', 'SomeValue', $text);
}
print_r($matches[1]);
print_r(str_replace('##', '', $text));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [0] => Name [1] => Adjective ) 
Hi My Name is SomeValue and I am SomeValue
```

But I am not able to handle deifferent variations of the string for example.

```
1. $text = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name}{Adjective}##'
2. $text = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name}and I am{Adjective}##'
3. $text = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name}, {Adjective}##'
4. $text = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name} {Adjective}##'
```

I would want the similar result in array output so that values can be replaced

```
 Array ( [0] => Name [1] => Adjective )
```

NOTE: I am able to ensure that '##' will always be present at the start and end of the curly braces, but not necessarily in between the braces e.g. point 1,2,3,4 above in example string.

Comment: why don't u just replace {Name} and {Adjective} with the value you want ?

Comment: Have you tried `/{([^#]+?)}/i`?

Comment: Try preg_match_all("/{[a-zA-Z]*}/", $input_lines, $output_array)

Comment: Lazy repeaters are really good for this, ie `/\{(.+?)\}/`. Your `([^#]+)}` repeater is matching `Name}{Adjective` in text #1 for example

Comment: @Phil & #Biffen solution provided by both of you worked for me. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with the pattern `/\{(.+?)}/` and a callback like this

```
$callback = function($matches) use (&$found) {
  $found[] = $matches[1];
  return 'SomeValue';
};
```

This will let you record the matches in the `$found` array while replacing the entire `{Name}`, `{Adjective}` with "SomeValue".

```
$found = [];
$newTxt = str_replace('##', '',
    preg_replace_callback('/\{(.+?)}/', $callback, $txt));
```

Demo here ~ https://eval.in/641827

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, you could first extract all the stuff that are between `## ##`, parse it, then replace it afterwards.

```
$text1 = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name}{Adjective}##';
$text2 = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name}and I am{Adjective}##';
$text3 = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name}, {Adjective}##';
$text4 = 'Hi My Name is ##{Name} {Adjective}##';

$the_text = $text2;

#get the stuff that's between ## ## 
preg_match_all("/##.*?##/", $the_text, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
{
    # you will have to change this a bit as you have name and adjectives
    # but what this does is replace all the '{}' with 'somevalue'
    $replace_this = preg_replace("/\{.*?\}/", "somevalue", $match);
    # replaces the original matched part with the replaced part (into the original text)
    $the_text = str_replace($match, $replace_this, $the_text);
}
echo $the_text . "<br>";
```

Comment: I think OP wants to also capture the "Name", "Adjective", etc parts in an array

Comment: @Phil It does that, I just went the extra step of doing the replacement as well.